# Nested DIV layout using CSS extends beyond boundary

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm developing a layout using DIVs and CSS to look like the image below. The elements should resize dynamically as the browser is resized.  I've got the layout to look very similar.  However, as you can see in this [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sivakanesh/0rjtzj1m/2/), the height of the 'Sidebar Content' is much longer, and the width of the 'Image Block' is wider than it should be.

Because of this, I get both the vertical and horizontal scrollbars in the browser.  I understand this is due to the height of the 'Sidebar Content' set to 100% height and width of the 'Image Block' set to 100%, but I'm not sure how to correct it and at the same time make the height & the width to fit within the layout.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

### Desired Layout

[image: Desired Layout]

### How it looks on a browser

[image: How it looks on a browser]

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sivakanesh/0rjtzj1m/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="top_block root_container">
        <div id="brand_header" class="content">
        Header 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="address_bar" class="top_block search_block">
        <div class="content">
        Header 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="additional_features" class="top_block">
        <div class="content">
        Header 3
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="content_block_parent">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="result_filter">
        Sidebar Header
        </div>
        <div id="result_list">
            Sidebar Content </br>
            sdgsdg</br>
            sdgsdg</br>
            sdgsdg</br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="image_block">
    Image Block 
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_block">
        <div class="content">
        Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top_block {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
}

.bottom_block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0; 
    background-color: #555;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.left_block {
    display: block;
    float: left; 
}

.right_block {
    display: block;
    float: right; 
}

.center_block {
    display: block;
    width: auto; 
}

.root_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.search_block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #9966ff;
}

#content_block_parent{
    style="width:100%; height:100%;
}

#result_list {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:45px;
    bottom:205px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#result_filter{
    position: absolute;
    /*  display: block;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #9966ff;
    top: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 153px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#666;
    width:300px;
}

#image_block{
    position: absolute;
    top: 153px;
    float: left;
    margin-left:300px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#666eee;
}

#address_bar{
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #acf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #acf;
    height: 47px;
    background: #fcfcfb url("vlb.jpg") 0 0 repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(55,55,55,0.1) inset,0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(55,55,55,0.1) inset,0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(55,55,55,0.1) inset,0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    height: 40px;
}

#brand_header{
    height: 36px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#additional_features{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

Comment: Can't see whats wrong could you clarify your issue because i can see the sidebar content and image block the same size

Comment: Please see the additional image.  It illustrates how it looks on a browser. All other elements fit to the current frame of the browser. You need to scroll to see the problematic ones.

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to solve it without jquery/JS, because both elements are in the middle and have to resize width and height. Would a jquery solution be OK? I would calculate the height and width everytime the windows get resized.

Comment: -1. Start by removing unnecessary content DIVs. Reduce the problem to as few divs as possible, then re-post your problem.

Comment: Well then it's not the layout I'm developing is it? This is hardly a complex layout to understand.

Comment: I think he's talking about divitis: http://csscreator.com/divitis

Comment: Content blocks are there so that the content can be styled independently to the layout CSS.  How doe it make it a bad question?

Comment: From my point of view, the question is ok. I really like your pictures! They are illustrating your problem very well. What about my answer?

Comment: I'm currently looking at your solution vs pure CSS.  Will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a solution without using JS.  And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sivakanesh/q40jzxak/) solution works fine.  The CSS can be optimised further I guess.  But the elements fit together and resize as expected.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sivakanesh/q40jzxak/)

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="top_block root_container">
        <div id="brand_header" class="content">
        Header 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="address_bar" class="top_block search_block">
        <div class="content">
        Header 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="additional_features" class="top_block">
        <div class="content">
        Header 3
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="content_block_parent">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="result_filter">
        Sidebar Header
        </div>
        <div id="result_list">
            Sidebar Content </br>
            sdgsdg</br>
            ...
            sdgsdg</br>
            sdgsdg</br>
            sdgsdg</br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="img_container">
        <div id="img_block">
             1234567890 1234567890
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_block">
        <div class="content">
        Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    min-width:800px; 
    min-height:450px;
}


.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top_block {
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    min-width: 800px;
}

.bottom_block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0; 
    background-color: #555;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.left_block {
    display: block;
    float: left; 
}

.right_block {
    display: block;
    float: right; 
}

.center_block {
    display: block;
    width: auto; 
}

.root_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.search_block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #9966ff;
}

#result_list {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:198px;
    bottom:50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
}


#result_filter{
    position: absolute;
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #9966ff;
    top: 153px;
}

#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#666;
    width:300px;
    z-index: -100;
}

#img_container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    background-color:#555;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -101;  
    margin-left: 300px;
    background-color:#222eee;
}

#img_block{
    position:absolute;
    top:153px;
    left:300px;
    bottom:50px;
    right: 0px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color:#666eee;
}

#address_bar{
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #acf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #acf;
    height: 47px;
    background: #fcfcfb url("vlb.jpg") 0 0 repeat;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(55,55,55,0.1) inset,0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(55,55,55,0.1) inset,0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(55,55,55,0.1) inset,0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    height: 40px;
}

#brand_header{
    height: 36px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#additional_features{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery, try this solution.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var height = $( window ).height();
    var width = $( window ).width();
    height -= $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height() - otherDivs;
    width -= $("#sidebar").width() - otherDivs; 
    $( "#sidebar" ).height(height);
    $( "#imageblock" ).height(height);
    $( "#imageblock" ).width(width);
});
```

This worked for me at least.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Olli.  The answer I have posted uses no JS.  Your solution works fine, but wanted to develop something with just CSS.